# How to check if number exists after a substring in string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Here are my to strings which is are url from a search page in my site.

```
http://localhost/healthlincs/find/10/?lat=-38.416097&lng=-63.616671999999994&query=a&filter=distance&show=clinic

http://localhost/healthlincs/find/?lat=-38.416097&lng=-63.616671999999994&query=a&filter=distance&show=clinic
```

Here only the different between to strings is one have `/10` after `find/` substring and another dont have `/10`. This 10 can be any number later like `20, 30, 40` etc. How can i know that number exists or not after `/find` substring on this url string?

 And how can i replace first string to second string? If there `/10` or `/20` exists i want to replace it with empty.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple enough using [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) :

```
var match = url..match(/\/find\/(\d+)\//);
if (match) {
    // your number is match[1]
```

If you want to remove that part, you can do it like this :

```
url = url.replace(/(\/find)\/\d+\//,'$1');
```

Note that you should try to understand those regular expressions to tune them for your real needs.

Comment: Or `RegExp#test` without the capture group, if the OP really just needs to know whether it's there, not what it is (as it *seems* from the question, but...).

Comment: Thanks it works. How can i replace first string to second string? If there `/10` or `/20` exists i want to replace it with empty

Answer (score 1):

```
^(https?:\/\/.*\/find\/)(?=(?:10|20))\d+\/(.*)$
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `$1$2`.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/47

```
    var re = /^(https?:\/\/.*\/find\/)(?=(?:10|20))\d+\/(.*)$/gim;
var str = 'http://localhost/healthlincs/find/10/?lat=-38.416097&lng=-63.616671999999994&query=a&filter=distance&show=clinic\n\nhttp://localhost/healthlincs/find/?lat=-38.416097&lng=-63.616671999999994&query=a&filter=distance&show=clinic\n\nhttp://localhost/healthlincs/find/30/?lat=-38.416097&lng=-63.616671999999994&query=a&filter=distance&show=clinic';
var subst = '$1$2';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Why there is a need for lookahead while `^https?:\/\/.*\/find\/\d+.*$` would be fine.

Comment: I just edited the question. Can you check it guys please. Thanks for help

Comment: @KrishnaKarki `string.replace(/(\/find)\/\d+/, "$1")`